# Redirect winterba.sh to the new site

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2013

[Winterba.sh](http://winterba.sh) is redirecting to the old 2012 site:
[image: old site]

Shouldn't it redirect to [winterbash2013.stackexchange.com](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Epic picture btw.